# Double click event not working on Windows 7 + IE 11 when control does not have focus

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-11

My system configuration is Windows 7 service pack1, 64 bit operation system and IE version is 11.0.9600.17843 (update version 11.0.20).

Kindly check this url provided by MSDN for double click event:

http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/workshop/samples/author/dhtml/refs/ondblclickEX.htm

To reproduce issue on Windows 7 + IE 11 follow below step:

1. Move focus to address bar by clicking on address bar.
2. Now double click on text box, double click event does not fire.

This issue does not reproduce on Windows 8 + IE 11 OR Windows 7 + IE version < 11.

Below is the code copied from: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536921(v=vs.85).aspx

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function addItem()
{
sNewItem = new Option(txtEnter.value)
selList.add(sNewItem);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Enter text and then double-click in the text box to
   add text to the list box.</p>
<input type="text" name="txtEnter" value="Enter_text" 
   ondblclick="addItem()"><br><br>
<select name="selList" size="5"></select>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm also getting this double click issue for ActiveX control created in VB6 for environment Windows 7 + IE 11.

My ActiveX application working fine on Windows 8 + IE 11.

Kindly provide me any solution or workaround for this issue.

Comment: [Seems to work fine](http://jsfiddle.net/3ryqe1j7/) in IE11, but not in FF or Chrome. A direct reference to HTML element using its `name` has been deprecated over a decade ago, you should use `id` attribute and `getElementById()` method instead. Just a sidenote, some of the code examples at MSDN are really old and out-of-date, like the one you've linked. I can see that exactly same example in an old MS Office guide where there's a text "© 1999 microsoft corporation" in the footer ; ).

Comment: Hi,

I have tried the above  but unfortunately I still have the same problem. Any other suggestions?

Thank you

Rajendra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To work around this issue, follow these steps to enable double click event of the control which does not already have focus.

1. Click Start, click Run, type regedit in the Open box, and then click OK.
2. Locate and then click the following registry sub key: HKEY_Current_User\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main
3. Right-click Main, point to New, and then select DWORD (32-bit) Value.
4. Type HangRecovery as the name, and then press Enter.
5. Set the default value to 0 in the Value data box.
6. Exit Registry Editor.
7. Clear the cache of internet explorer.